# How to get value from more than two table laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, closures

i'm having problem with eloquent laravel. I can't get data from my table.
**This is the requirement : Get list user and sum value from table test_1, test_2, and test_3.**
This is my table :
User table :

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });
```

test_1 table :

```
Schema::create('tests_1', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->smallInteger('test_a')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('test_b')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
        });
```

test_2 table :

```
Schema::create('tests_2', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->smallInteger('test_a')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('test_b')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
        });
```

test_3 table :

```
Schema::create('tests_3', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->smallInteger('test_a')->nullable();
            $table->smallInteger('test_b')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users');
        });
```

My Controller :

```
$users = User::with(['test1' => function($query){
                        $query->select('*', DB::raw("SUM(test_a + test_b) as score1"));
                    }])
                    ->with(['test2' => function($query){
                        $query->select('*', DB::raw("SUM(test_a + test_b) as score2"));
                    }])
                    ->with(['test3' => function($query){
                        $query->select('*', DB::raw("SUM(test_a + test_b) as score3"));
                    }])
                    ->get();


        return view('home', compact('users'));
```

My view :

```
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Total Score 1</th>
                            <th>Total Score 2</th>
                            <th>Total Score 3</th>
                        </tr>
                        @foreach($users as $key=> $user)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $user->username }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->test->score1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->test->score2 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->test->score3 }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </table>
```

I'm getting error and stuck on there.

My models :
User model :

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function test1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Test1');
    }

    public function test2()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Test2');
    }

    public function test3()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Test3');
    }
}
```

Test1 model :

```
class Test1 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tests_1';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'test_a', 'test_b',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Test2 model :

```
class Test2 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tests_2';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'test_a', 'test_b',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Test3 model :

```
class Test3 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tests_3';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'test_a', 'test_b',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: _I'm getting error and stuck on there._ wow, we should guess what's the error?..

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what error? and any reason you are creating different id field types for these 3 tables?

Comment: This is the error : **Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.test_1' doesn't exist (SQL: select *, SUM(test_a + test_b) as score1 from `test_1` where `test_1`.`user_id` in (1, 2))**.

Comment: @lagbox Because I have a different kind of 'test'. I have 3 types of tests which each have 2 questions.

Comment: nvm ... your error says it can't find the table named `test_1` since you named it `tests_1` so you will have to set the table name in that model for the `tests_1` table

Comment: As your error says that no test tables found 

In your user model you have relation of all test tables ?

Comment: @yuhha post your model definitions how these models are related to each other

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid I've updated my models.

Comment: @yuhha models looks fine but the error you have posted in comments is different it says there is no `test_1` table in your database which seems quite odd. Can you execute `select *, SUM(test_a + test_b) as score1 from test_1 where test_1.user_id in (1, 2)` directly on your database using any tool like phpmyadmin, mysqlbench or sqlyog

Comment: thanks @MKhalidJunaid , i'll try it..